# Http error 500.19 with no error message?

Tags: iis, sitecore7

I am currently trying to locally run a website using Sitecore but seem to get some weird error when trying to enter the page. The error message is blank?
 And the error code is `500.19`.

I read somewhere else that this could be due to the authentication is given by IIS didn't allow me to enter the page, when I try to enter the authentication page in IIS prompt an error message with no message - besides an error occurred, and then the path to my `erb.config` file.

`Error code: 0x8007000d`

but the `web.config` cannot work on other pc - with the same setup.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if your IIS / machine where you try to run the sitecore project has proper .net framework installed. I think if you are trying to run latest sitecore version then check if you have .net framework 4.0 installed properly with your iis.

The issues seems to be your machine issue and lesser of the sitecore related.

thanks,

Hiral

Answer (score 0):

I got this error too, I had all the required .NET framework and .NET Core runtimes. Was just missing the Url Rewrite module in IIS.

Hope this helps someone.